# Unable to make a connection to the Parity Secure API

Tags: parity, tokens, secure-signer

Parity V1.4.9 giving this error on startup frequently.

> Unable to make a connection to the Parity Secure API. To update your
>   secure token or to generate a new one, run parity signer new-token and
>   supply the token below

How can I fix this and how can I prevent it happening again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter what the message tells you: `parity signer new-token`

```
0 ✓ user@alcor ~ $ parity signer new-token
2017-01-17 14:38:08  This key code will authorise your System Signer UI: xISW-3Sx9-AxLx-xUxO
```

Where `xISW-3Sx9-AxLx-xUxO` is your token. Enter it in the field popping up after launching the parity browser window. This will authorize your access to the wallet and browser.

You can think of it as a security feature, just like you have to enter your PIN on your mobile once in a while.